# Bottom Tab navigator not visible in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm beginner in this tech. I have problem in my navigation.

After logging in of the use, it will redirect to a screen with Bottom tab navigator, my bottom tab navigator compose of 5 tabs, tab 1,2,3,4,5, and each tab have its corresponding page. In tab 2 which is the STORE page, when I click the tab 2, a list of store appear. I store the STORE name in a touchable opacity, when the user click the store name, it will redirect to PRODUCT SCREEN, but this time the bottom tab navigation is NOT VISIBLE. So in that screen, a list of products offered by the store selected from previous screen.

Same also, I store or put the product item list in a touchableopacity, when the time user click that product, it will redirect to PRODUCT DETAILS screen, and still the bottom tab navigator is not visible or disappear. In the PRODUCT DETAILS screen, it shows the details of product selected, a button "place order" and CART ICON, which if the user tap it, it will redirect to TAB 1 which is ORDER PAGE.

[image: This is the visual representation of my problem.].

And my expected output that even move to another screen, the bottom tab navigator won't disappear or still visible, and also that cart icon, if click it must move to TAB 1 which is order page.

This is my code and what I've tried.

app.js

```js
return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
      initialRouteName="login"
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="BottomTabNavigator"
        component={myBottomTabnavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarVisible: true,
        }}
      />

      <Stack.Screen name="login" component={loginpage} />

      <Stack.Screen name="register" component={registerPage} />

      <Stack.Screen name="forgotpass" component={ForgotPassword} />

      <Stack.Screen name="ordernavigation" component={myorderStackNavigation} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Products" component={ProductScreens} />

      <Stack.Screen
        name="ProductDetailsAndOrder"
        component={ProductDetailAndPlaceOrder}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

myBottomTabnavigator.js

```js
<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Tab1"
    component={tab1}
    options={{
      tabBarVisible: true,
    }}
  />

  <Tab.Screen
    name="Tab2"
    component={Tab2}
    options={{
      tabBarVisible: true,
    }}
  />

  <Tab.Screen
    name="Tab3"
    component={tab3}
    options={{
      tabBarVisible: true,
    }}
  />

  <Tab.Screen
    name="Tab4"
    component={tab4}
    options={{
      tabBarVisible: true,
    }}
  />

  <Tab.Screen
    name="Tab 5"
    component={tab2}
    options={{
      tabBarVisible: true,
    }}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

myorderStackNavigation.js

```js
return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="productscreen" component={ProductScreens} />

      <Stack.Screen
        name="productDetails_Order"
        component={ProdDetailsScreen}
      />


    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

productDetails_Order.js --- in my cart icon, I made like this.

```js
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    navigation.navigate("Tab1");
  }}
></TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: To rephrase: You have User Login&SignUp after which the user will land on the purchasing screens that are navigated via the tabs while some screens will also allow navigation within the same tab to show more infos. Is that about right?

Comment: Yes, it is right sir.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your different navigators. I would start with a Stack.Navigator in your navigation index file which contains then your bottom navigator with all the tabs.
The bottom navigator then contains all screens AND where needed it contains another Stack to have the details screens there (or if you dont use screens there rather a modal then you dont need another navigator, but I think you wanted it that way)

something like this:

```
 <NavigationContainer
    ref={navigationRef}>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Splash">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Splash"
        component={Splash}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    
      <Stack.Screen
        name="BottomNavigator"
        component={BottomNavigator}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="UnAuthorizedNavigator"
        component={UnAuthNavigator}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
```

then Bottomnav:

```
<Bottom.Navigator
    ref={navigationRef}>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Splash">
      <Bottom.Screen
        name="ProductStack"
        component={ProductStack}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Bottom.Screen
        name="AnotherStep"
        component={AnotherStep}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      [...]
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </Bottom.Navigator>
```

and now missing only your Product Stack with main and details screen as well as the UnAuthorizedNavigator Stack where you have all your SignUp and Login screens.

Comment: so sir, I will replace my code in app.js or as is?

Comment: oh please never do the same in the app.js - implement the first stack as "rootnavigator" in the index.js file in a navigation folder and then  you handle all navigators as mentioned above. In App.js you then have only something like:  <Provider store={store}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <RootNavigator />
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </Provider>

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use

```
<TouchableOpacity   
  onPress={() => {   
// navigation.navigate("Tab1"); 
   navigation.navigate('myBottomTabnavigator', { screen: 'Tab1' })
  }}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

it will navigate to the "Tab1" screen within the "myBottomTabnavigator,"

**NOTE:** Here the screen will the name of the component

eg:<Tab.Screen name="**Tab1**" component={**myBottomTabnavigator**} />

from the above the name in the tab.screen will be given in screen:''